# Jupyter notebook gives warning on an error

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

Jupyter gives a warning on an error (it still ignores the error and my codes can run fine)
[image: warnings]

How can I disable such warnings, since it could make my kernel too heavy from the warnings?
I tried this but didn't work

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
```

Comment: Error and warning is different. Error message is infeasible work because of some problems. You should look at the problem and solve it, no by ignoring it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import warnings;
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore');
```

To stop normal warnings from showing up